# Return class type and have class type as parameter

Tags: java, class

I have function

```
private Class readObject (ObjectInput in, Class objectclass){
    try {
        Object o = in.readObject ();

        if (o instanceof objectclass) {
            return (objectclass)o;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

}
```

In my class I am calling this function with:

```
ObjectInput in = (..)
Type1 type = readObject (in, Type1.class);
(do something with type)
while(true){
    Type2 type2 = readObject (in, Type2.class);
    (do something with type2)
```

Basically, readObject is supposed to return the class that I have as a parameter, if that is the correct type of Object o. You can think of this as, I have Type1, Type2 and Type3 objects that I am reading, but if I come across Type3 I do nothing.

This code that I have written does not work properly. For example,

```
Type1 type = readObject (in, Type1.class);
```

gives me the warning "cannot convert from Class to Type1".

Comment: Do you have three different classes called `Class`, `Type1`, and `Type2`?

Comment: Type1 and Type2 are classes yes. "Class" is my way of trying to return a class. I also tried Class<?> and Class<T>, does not seem to help

Comment: Because the return type must be an instance of `Type1`or `Type2` but you are returning an instance of `Class`

Comment: Interesting mismatch between "goal" and "skills". Meaning: on the one hand, you want to work on **complex** functionality; on the other hand, your seem to be (yet) unable to read very basic compiler error messages. And no, it is not a *warning*, the compiler is telling you that you have a hard mismatch between what your method returns, and what the caller of the method expects. So, besides the answer you already got: I would really recommend you to spend some time learning the **essential basics** of java, before further fighting with **advanced** topics like reflection ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should make your method generic and return an instance of `T` (instead of an instance of `Class<T>`):

```
private <T> T readObject (ObjectInput in, Class<T> objectclass)
```

**EDIT:** You should also change your `if` and your cast, as follows:

```
if (objectclass.isInstance(o)) {
    return (T) o;
}
```

Comment: I tried this. `return (objectclass)o;` does not work

Comment: @hokosha What about `return (Class<T>)o;` ?

Comment: You should cast to `T`, like this: `return (T) o;`

Comment: Any ideas on how the if-statement should be?

Answer (score 5):

You have 2 things to do:

1. Change the signature of your method as next:

   `private <T> T readObject (ObjectInput in, Class<T> objectclass) {`
2. Cast your object dynamically using `Class.cast` as next:

   `return objectclass.cast(o);`